# Prove that $W_1,W_2$ subspaces are subsets of $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question:

> Given two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$:
>
> $W_1 = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | x_1 + x_3 = x_2 + x_4, x_1 - x_3 = x_2 - x_4 \}$.
> $W_2 = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | x_1 + x_3 = -x_2 - x_4, x_1 - x_3 = -x_2 + x_4 \}$.
>
> We also given a set $Q = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | x_1  x_3 = x_2  x_4 \}$
>
> Prove that $W_1,W_2 \subseteq Q$, and check if Q is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I managed to prove that $Q$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$: We can see that $(2,4,4,2),(1,0,0,0) \in Q$ but it is not closed under addition: $(2,4,4,2)+(1,0,0,0)=(3,4,4,2)$ which $3\times 4 \neq 4\times 2 \Rightarrow 12 \neq 8$.

But I can't seem to prove that $W_1,W_2 \subseteq Q$... I know that I need to show that for each $a \in W_1$ there exists an $a \in Q$, but I'm not sure how to do that here... Can I get a hint please?

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct that $Q$ is not a subspace.  As for showing they are subsets... can you show that elements of $W_1$ would have that $x_1$ and $x_2$ have the same sign?  or $x_3$ and $x_4$ would have the same sign, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $W_1$ is the space $\{(a,a,b,b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$, whereas the space $W_2$ is the space $\{(a,-a,b,-b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$. And $W_1\subset Q$, since $a\times b=a\times b$. Finally, $W_2\subset Q$, since $a\times b=(-a)\times(-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

On simplifying the two conditions in $W_1$, each vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in W_1$ satisfy $x_1=x_2, x_3=x_4$ which eventually is one of the solution of the condition given in $Q$. Similarly, each vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in W_2$ satisfy $x_1=-x_2, x_3=-x_4$ which is yet another solution of the condition $x_1x_3=x_2x_4$.